# Add a player to a scoreboard if they aren't already on it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Sadly, I couldn't find this answer anywhere.

I'm going to refer to `[score_deaths=1]` as selectors, as I don't know their proper name.

Is there a selector for if a player isn't on a scoreboard (f.e. `@a[score_not_on_deaths]` or `@a[score_deaths!]`)

Or, even better, is there a way to say player `A` just joined, he isn't on the scoreboard, `/scoreboard players set A deaths 0`

Is there a way or a workaround? Also, this is using a `/fill` clock, so you can only use one command. Thanks!

Comment: You can use more than one command with a fill clock. You just need to adjust your clock to fill an area greater than one block

Answer (score 6):

You can add all players to a scoreboard and keep all other players unaffected by adding 0 to the score for everyone:

```
/scoreboard players add @a deaths 0
```

All players without a score will have their score set to zero. All other players will be unaffected.